# Yammer Dev Documentation for possible reference return types?

Tags: yammer

when getting back references from Yammer through the dev api, they can be of a few different types. Is there any documentation somewhere that describes the JSON model of returned objects?

Right now I have got the following from just reading the returned JSON.

```
Type:
- "user"
- "guide"
- "group"
- "thread"
- "topic"
```

But there could be other types I'm not expecting which could be sent in the future. Is there a list somewhere that describes indepth all the possible return types from the Yammer API?

Answer (score 0):

There's not currently any documentation resource that will provide that information. It's also possible for additional reference types to be added later.

To deal with references robustly, you'll need to add code to handle the reference types you know about and do *something reasonable* for reference types you don't recognize.

The *something reasonable* may vary, but a good start would be to somehow log the reference and otherwise ignore it.